# Can't open session in facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I cant open a session in facebook's latest sdk in android. When I debug my code it shows session state:"OPENING" -> not "OPEN". I am stacked in this issue for couple days and there is no such kind of problem on internet, so please help me.
Here is my example Main Class:

```
public class Miranda extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final TextView userNameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            // callback when session changes state
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {

                    // make request to the /me API
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                        // callback after Graph API response with user object
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                userNameView.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");

//                                profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.Miranda"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="Miranda"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
                  android:label="@string/title_facebook_login">
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

and lastly strings.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Miranda</string>
    <string name="app_id">241765162664333</string>
    <string name="title_facebook_login">Log Into Facebook</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guys I can be the fastest man who solves his problem immediately after telling it in stackoverflow. The problem was: I deleted an overridden function when cleaning other stupid trying codes. I added it again into my main class:

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```